# Secondary/Failover power for board

Tags: power

I designed a board and I want to have two ways of delivering power to it. Smooth failover would be nice but is *not* a goal. The main focus is flexibility. Here are the requirements:

- Primary power: can be any fixed voltage, preferably 5 or 12V, not more.
- Secondary power: anywhere between 5 and 24V depending on use case.
- If primary power is present, it should be used. Otherwise secondary power should be used.
- Worst case the board should run from 5V secondary power.

There's a power block on the board that accepts up to 30V so no need for voltage regulation. OR'ing diodes could be used but that would violate priorities if secondary voltage is higher than primary. Unfortunately I don't know enough about power circuits to design this. I would like to avoid using ICs if possible. MOSFETs seemed promising, but couldn't figure out a way to accomplish this. I appreciate any ideas, pointers, tips&tricks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution with discrete components:

*NOTE: The component selection did not consider your actual current and power values. The MOSFETs and the diode would have to be rated accordingly*

**Essentially how it works:**

The primary power supply takes precedence over the secondary one, by controlling the latter via a PMOS based ORing, which is connected to two inverters. 
If the primary's voltage is high enough, it will turn on \$Q_2\$, which turns off \$Q_1\$, which in turn turns off the back-to-back MOSFETs \$M_1\$ and \$M_2\$. The threshold, at which you want to have the transition from one power supply to another, can be determined by the resistors \$R_4\$ and \$R_5\$ and the BJT's \$V_{BE}\$. For a more precise transition point, let's say, if the primary supply voltage falls below \$4 V\$ the secondary power supply is connected, you can use a comparator.

As you can see in  the waveform, the load is only sourced with the current from the active power supply.

**EDIT #1**

1. Reduce the turn-on / off time of the ORing by charging its gate capacitance to no more than \$4.7V\$ (No need for overcharging it). It also reduces power losses during the transition.
2. Asymmetrical charging and discharging of the gate capacitance via \$R_1\$ and \$R_6\$ adds hysteresis to the transition e.g. \$V_{OFF}=6.4V\$ and \$V_{ON}=8.13V\$
3. Resistive load replaced with a constant \$10W\$ power load

[image: circuit]

[image: waveform]

Comment: Not bad, but I wonder about MOSFET dissipation during that slow transition from V2 back to V1 for a sufficiently slow  If you added a little hysteresis (like 10M from Q1c to Q2b) will that clean up?

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: I have a question though: if the voltage on Q1's collector just follows the primary (in an "on/off" sense), then why do I need the double inverting BJTs? Can't I just route `primary` there through a resistor and pull it down with a 10k resistor? Since I can choose the primary voltage, I don't care about transitioning at a specific voltage; it's either there or not. Or what about replacing R2, R4, R5, Q1 and Q2 with another PMOS?

Comment: @BrianDrummond Good point. The MOSFET \$M_2\$ will suffer the most during the transition because of the voltage difference between both sources and their slow slew rate. Furthermore its relatively large gate capacitance has to be discharged, before it is completely off. I updated the circuit with some improvements, e.g. hysteresis.

Comment: @SzabolcsSzekelyi If you would pull down the base of \$Q_1\$ directly with your first supply, you would need a very low voltage, e.g. \$V_{PRI}\approx 700mV\$, meaning that your load would not be supplied for a few miliseconds. As long as you had enough capacitance at the output to buffer this transition, it would work. To your second question, the primary would be able to turn on the secondary one (PMOS on), but due to the voltage difference between both supplies, for some specific region (e.g. \$V_{SEC}=24V\$ \$V_{PRI}<V_{SEC}-V_{th}\$) the PMOS would not turn off completely.

Comment: @vtolentino Which software did you use to draw and simulate the circuit?

Comment: @SzabolcsSzekelyi It is freeware software called LTSpice.